# How to power Arduino Pro Mini via VCC pin (12v input)

Tags: arduino, power-supply, power

According to the [Arduino Pro Mini spec](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardProMini) it has Input Voltage of 5 - 12 V (5V model). Is it possible to input 12v by using any method other than usb? If so are there any downsides/limitations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to feed 12v to the board then you should use the raw input which feeds the onboard regulator input and will step down the voltage to 5v (vcc).

[image]

You should not connect any voltage >5v to Vcc or USB directly

The location of the raw input pin on the board is

[image]

Comment: Not sure how I didn't realise 12V via usb wasn't right :) Arduino Nano looses 3.3V pin when not powered via usb, is there anything similar with Arduino Mini?

Comment: @DominicM You said you want to feed the board with a voltage 9-12v , you can do that from the RAW input. For a 5v version of the board there is no 3v3 so I'm nor sure what you are asking or how the USB input related to the question.

Comment: That's my mistake, I was mixing them up.

Comment: Does 12v make the onboard regulator very hot?

Comment: @MikeCauser Yes, there [are people destroying their Micro Pro with 12V](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/78370/arduino-pro-mini-is-burned-by-12v-can-i-save-it) [Arduino SE]

Answer (score 1):

You could also connect a diode to the raw input and the 12V to the diode. This drops a little voltage & prevents connecting the power in reverse.  Not sure if it would damage the regulator to apply reverse voltage, but adding the diode doesn't hurt anything.